# How to read from a text file and store multiple values to a key in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

My text file is of the form:

```
ABC,_XYZ 45.1976844 -69.458819
AWA,_WES 44.946356 -90.315969
AXA,_WWA 36.3055851 -104.2588701
```

How do I store this in a dictionary with the letters including ',' and '_' are the keys and the numbers are two different values of that key.

Comment: You mean a dictionary where for example: `my_dict["ABC,_XYZ"] = [45.1976844, -69.458819]`, i.e. the letters are the keys and the two numbers are the values for that key, right?

Comment: @today yeah. The answer below has already solved that. could you tell me how to access each value separately?

Comment: The value is a list so you can access its elements using integer indices: `dicta["ABC,_XYZ"][0]` and `dicta["ABC,_XYZ"][1]`.

Comment: Thanks,  but it turns out the text file I have has multiple/duplicate keys with different values and the code below is only storing the latest one. How do I get all the key - values pairs ? @today

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dicta = dict()
with open("yourfile.txt", "r") as file:
    for i in file:
        line, *lines = i.split()
        dicta[line] = lines
```

.split() will only split it at the spaces

the dict look like this

```
{'ABC,_XYZ': ['45.1976844', '-69.458819'], 
'AWA,_WES': ['44.946356', '-90.315969'], 
'AXA,_WWA': ['36.3055851', '-104.2588701']}
```

here line takes the first value and *lines just takes the rest

**UPDATE**

```
dicta = dict()
with open("yourfile.txt", "r") as file:
    for i in file:
        line, *lines = i.split()
        if line in dicta:
            dicta[line] += lines
        else:
            dicta[line] = lines


dicta = dict()
with open("yourfile.txt", "r") as file:
    for w,i in enumerate(file):
        line, *lines = i.split()
        if line in dicta:
            dicta[w] = lines
        else:
            dicta[line] = lines

dicta = list()
with open("yourfile.txt", "r") as file:
    for w,i in enumerate(file):
        line, *lines = i.split()
        dicta.append((line,lines))
```

Comment: Also, how would I access each value separately for every key?

Comment: it's a dictionary so you just say dicta[one of the letter keys][the index of the list] f.x. dicta['AWA,_WES'][1] is '-90.315969'

Comment: Okay, but it turns out the text file I have has multiple/duplicate keys with different values and this code is only storing the latest one. How do I get all the values ?

Comment: @inadvisableguy i have updated my answer so that it just adds it on the the old list if the key is already there.

Comment: I know this is a silly question, but is there a way in which I can form another key for the same object?

Comment: @inadvisableguy i have updated it again however you want to give it a new name so, now i just gave it the name of the number line it is if the key allready exists.

Comment: Oh alright, but the thing is, I need the exact name in front of it instead of the line number i.e. a duplicate key with the same name.

Comment: So which list do you want when you Call the key? I don't   Think you want to use dictionaries but rather a list of tuples kontaining the now Keys, and lists

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180164/discussion-between-inadvisableguy-and-jonas-wolff).